# jQuery Mobile linked list pageInit(), not $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a mobile version of a web page. My problem is that I have to manipulate a accordion menu to use jQuery mobile linked list. To do this I manipulate the menu with jQuery ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#globalMenu').attr("data-role", "listview");
    .. .. . . ..
});
```

It works great if I load the page first time, but when I navigate in the jQuery mobile list and push one of the link the script do not run, but if I refresh the page (<kbd>f5</kbd>) it works! I've read that I have to use init instead of document ready but I can't manage it to work.

Please write some examples.

[jQueryMobile event page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: `$(document).ready()` only runs when the page is loaded - no where else ... if you want to run your code else where you need to attach it to another event .. can you please include some other code with a pointer to where you want this code to run ?

Comment: You meen like this 

    $('#globalmenu').makeMyDay();  ??

Isn't there a event that runs everytime a page loads? I've tryed
    $('#globalmenu').live('pagecreate', function(event){
    console.log("make my day");
    });
without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your page `div` is like this:

```
<div id="my-page" data-role="page">
```

Try with:

```
$('#my-page').live('pageinit', function(event){
  $('#globalMenu').attr("data-role", "listview");
});
```

Comment: I would suggest using .jqmData() to figure out roles instead of the .attr() method, as written in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/methods.html)